# Marionette/puppet sci-fi show with replaced limbs and alien control

Tags: story-identification, tv

I watched this sci-fi show as a kid during the late 1980s in South Africa. The show itself likely came from Japan. It definitely wasn't a domestic production.

The show's protagonists were human like, in conflicts with aliens. The aliens captured many of the humans during the course of the show and somehow converted them to do their bidding. The conversion included the removing of one of the human's arms and replacing it with something either mechanical or insect like. The humans also then wore a type of head gear (very Borg-like), which allowed the aliens to control them.

Towards the end of the show, one of the humans controlled by the aliens was liberated and ended up helping the humans.

The name "Commander Mary" comes to mind, but it may have nothing to do with the original Japanese name.

Comment: Hello Judy, welcome to [fantasy.se] and thank you for your question. You've included the most important details. However, maybe [this checklist for asking ID requests](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/19561) will jog your memory. I see you're on a number of other Stacks, so I won't bother inviting you on the [tour], but may I invite you to drop by in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58631/the-restaurant-at-the-end-of-the-universe)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to your description, I'm quite sure it is *X-Bomber* (also known as *Star Fleet*), a Japanese puppet series.
From [Wikpedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Bomber):

> The year is 2999 and the Earth is at peace following the Space Wars.
>   The safety of the human race is ensured by Earth Defense Force (EDF).
>   Shortly before the turn of the fourth millennium, the peace is broken
>   by the appearance of a gigantic alien battle cruiser. Powerless to
>   defend itself, the EDF' Pluto base is completely destroyed and the
>   evil Commander Makara reveals that the same fate awaits the Earth
>   unless the mysterious F-Zero-One is handed over to her.

This is the link for the [Wikia of the show](http://star-fleet.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Fleet_Wiki).

This is the main starship:

[image: Main starship]

For instance one of the human characters was "converted" this way by the evil empire:

[image: Converted character]

Comment: Thanks! I remember the story very differently (it's been 30-35 years) but this looks like it was the one. It aired in South Africa under the title "Vegskip X".